# Как решить задачу правильно

Tags: c++

Задача состоит в следующем: Есть поле [n]*[n] которое хранит в себе некие объекты. Это карта, не ней могут быть существа и объекты. Все эти элементы сей час наследуются от единого интерфейса. Количество этих объектов заранее не известно. Существа могут перемещаться по карте, когда они наступают на какое то поле, нужно произвести действия. Отнять hp например. В данный момент получается, что я работаю не с объектами, а с их интерфейсами.
Почему используется интерфейс? Для хранения разномастных объектов в одном контейнере. Соответственно в классе Map у меня остались только указатели на интерфейсы и никакой информации о типе. 
Есть ли иной путь?

```
#include <iostream>

class IWorldObject {
 public:
  virtual ~IWorldObject() {}
  virtual void add(IWorldObject* wo) = 0;
  virtual void add(class Rock* wo) = 0;
  virtual void add(class Creature* wo) = 0;
  virtual void add(class Atmosphere* wo) = 0;
};

class Rock : public IWorldObject {
  virtual ~Rock() {}
  // IWorldObject interface
 public:
  void add(IWorldObject* wo) { wo->add(this); }
  void add(class Creature* creature) {std::cout << "summ for CREATURE and ROCK";}
  void add(Rock* wo) { std::cout << "summ for ROCK and ROCK"; }
  void add(Atmosphere* wo) { std::cout << "summ for ATMOSPHERE and ROCK"; }
};

class Creature : public IWorldObject {
  virtual ~Creature() {}
  // IWorldObject interface
 public:
  void add(IWorldObject* wo) { wo->add(this); }
  void add(Rock* rock) { std::cout << "summ for ROCK and CREATURE"; }
  void add(Creature* wo) { std::cout << "summ for CREATURE and CREATURE"; }
  void add(Atmosphere* wo) { std::cout << "summ for ATMOSPHERE and CREATURE"; }
};

class Atmosphere : public IWorldObject {
  virtual ~Atmosphere() {}
// IWorldObject interface
 public:
  void add(IWorldObject* wo) { wo->add(this); }
  void add(Rock* rock) { std::cout << "summ for ROCK and ATMOSPHERE"; }
  void add(Creature* wo) { std::cout << "summ for CREATURE and ATMOSPHERE"; }
  void add(Atmosphere* wo) {std::cout << "summ for ATMOSPHERE and ATMOSPHERE";}
};

int main() {
  IWorldObject* a = new Creature();
  IWorldObject* b = new Rock();
  IWorldObject* c = new Atmosphere();

  a->add(b);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  a->add(c);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  a->add(a);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  b->add(a);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  b->add(b);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  b->add(c);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  c->add(a);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  c->add(b);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  c->add(c);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete a;
  delete b;
  delete c;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хранить в поле объекты - так себе идея, лучше хранить в объектах (или в отдельном контейнере) их координаты. Что касается отсутствия информации о типах - это совсем верно. Дело в том, что нет информации о типе снаружи объекта - сам же объект знает какого он типа. Это отличный пример для использования визитера

Comment: Но ведь посетители разные. Не понимаю как мне поможет этот паттерн. Хранить координаты в объектах. Звучит странно, не понятно как проверять на что наступило существо, переместившись вверх. Выискивать в массиве объектов координаты объекта с которым мы столкнулись?

Comment: по поводу разных посетителей - все же потрудитесь изучить этот паттерн и ответ найдется сам собой. Что касается поиска - это уже отдельный функционал: коллизии. В любом случае это лишь рекомендация

Comment: Для чего вам нужна информция о типе?

Comment: Информация о типе нужна что бы понять как поступить с объектами дальше. Отнять hp, не дать пройти в стену и тд.

Comment: Ясно, теперь представим, что эта информация в виде строки, а  некооторый класс знает что делать, когда его экземпляр получает эту строку. Так сойдет?

Comment: Как бы не было, или  некоторая функция(класс) должна решить что делать с обьектом  того или иного типа, или же сам обьект должен знать как себя вести, если попал ту или в иную ситуацию.

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не сделать в `IWorldObject` переменную для обозначения своего типа, например: `int nType;` (а лучше `enum`). Потом сделать только один `add(IWorldObject * p);`. И потом делать внутри этого `add()` проверку `nType` и приводить к нужному типу через cast.

Comment: И чем это решение лучше или даже отличается от моего? Вы предлагаете большой switch case.

Comment: @WierdGreenCat в каждом классе-реализаторе будет 1 add, вместо 4. То есть съэкономим 9 функций

Comment: И большой switch. И множество cast в каждом. Этого старался избежать)